# Average in Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I am trying to find the average of maths score for the class but I am not sure how to do this within a dictionary. How do I use a simple method of adding each score then dividing this by the number of students (num_students)?

```
login="teacher"
password="school"

usrnm=input("Please enter your username: ")
pw=input("Please enter your password: ")
if (usrnm==login) and (pw==password):
   print("==Welcome to the Mathematics Score Entry Program==")
   num_students = int(input("Please enter number of students:"))
   print ("you entered ",num_students," students")
   student_info = {}
   student_data = ['Maths Score: ']
   for i in range(0,num_students):
      student_name = input("Name :")
      student_info[student_name] = {}
      for entry in student_data:
        student_info[student_name][entry] = int(input(entry)) 
   print (student_info)
else:
  print("No way, Jose!")
```

Comment: While it can be figured out., it would be really helpful to include a sample of what you expect the data to look like in your question.

Comment: Usually it is good idea to separate *input/output* from logic. So you should write a function that takes as input a dictionary and returns the average, but without all the interaction.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

python dictionaries have a `.values()` method which returns a list of the values in a dictionary which you can use, eg:

```
sum(d.values()) / float(len(d))
```

`d.values()` give the list of marks for your students, `sum(..)` gives the total of all the marks, which I divide by `len(d)` which is the integer length of the dictionary (ie the number of marks) obviously average is total of marks / number of marks.

you need the float because python 2 will return an integer otherwise (python 3 gives floats when appropriate)

Comment: An alternative in Python 2 is to provide an initial value for `sum`, eg: `sum(d.values(), 0.0) / len(d)`

Comment: @JonClements huh, never thought of doing it that way.

Comment: @JonClements Would you say that's more Pythonic though? I find the `float()` way more immediately readable.There is always `numpy.mean()` too, although probably overkill here...

Comment: @Chris_Rands not especially - just pointing it out... from Python 3.4, there's also `statistics.mean` similar to `numpy.mean`...

Comment: Can you please explain the following code: sum(d.values()) / float(len(d))

Comment: @MrFHHH sure, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 3):

Calculating the average can be done using the `sum` function as follows:

```
average = sum(d['Maths Score: '] for d in student_info.values()) / len(student_info)
```

Note that currently your code can only have students with unique names. Two students with the same name will override each other.

Comment: This is an extension activity that I am looking to implement but thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.4+, then you can use `statistics.mean`:

```
from statistics import mean
avg_score = mean(d.values())
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments as far. I am looking for the following output              "The average Maths score is . . . "

Comment: @MrFHHH so `print` the output of `avg_score` then?